# R - Filter matrix by duplicate values

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    1    3    5    1
[2,]    3    5    4    6    7    2
```

I need to filter this matrix so that I remove the columns with duplicate elements in row 1, leaving behind only columns with the max value in row 2. So in this example, columns 1 & 6 of the input matrix need to be removed:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    3    5
[2,]    5    4    6    7
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could compute the maximum second-row values for each first-row element and then only keep columns where the second row is the max value for the element in the first:

```
(maxes <- tapply(mat[2,], mat[1,], max))
# 1 2 3 5 
# 4 5 6 7 
(mat2 <- mat[,maxes[as.character(mat[1,])] == mat[2,]])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    1    3    5
# [2,]    5    4    6    7
```

If you expect to have ties for the maximum values in the second row and want to remove the duplicate columns, you can use `mat2[!duplicated(mat2[,1]),]` after these two commands.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ave`

```
 res <- mat[,!!ave(mat[2,], mat[1,], FUN=function(x) x==max(x))]
 res
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    2    1    3    5
 #[2,]    5    4    6    7
```

**NOTE:** If there are ties in the dataset, you can remove those columns by

```
 res[,!duplicated(split(res, col(res)))]
```